# Solution verification: find all continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)+f(2x)=0$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Find all continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)+f(2x)=0$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

I first notice that the function $g(x)\equiv0$ is continuous as function from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and it satisfies the equation because for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ it is $g(x)=0$ and $g(2x)=0$ so $g(x)+g(2x)=0+0=0$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

My question is about the validity of this argument to show that $g$ is the unique continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the equation: assume that there is another continuous function $h:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, with $h(x) \not\equiv 0$, such that $h(x)+h(2x)=0$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Since $h(x) \not\equiv 0$, there exists $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(x_0)>0$ or $h(x_0)<0$; I assume WLOG $h(x_0)>0$. Since $h$ is continuous, there exists $r>0$ such that $h(x)>0$ for any $x \in (x_0-r,x_0+r)$. So $h(2x)>0$ for any $x \in \left(\frac{x_0-r}{2},\frac{x_0+r}{2}\right)$.

But $\left(\frac{x_0-r}{2},\frac{x_0+r}{2}\right) \subset (x_0-r,x_0+r)$, hence for any $x\in \left(\frac{x_0-r}{2},\frac{x_0+r}{2}\right)$ it is $h(x)>0$ and $h(2x)>0$, so for any $x \in \left(\frac{x_0-r}{2},\frac{x_0+r}{2}\right)$ it is $h(x)+h(2x)>0$ but this contradicts that $h(x)+h(2x)=0$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Is this a valid proof of the uniqueness of $g$?

Comment: I think your intervals are not related in the way you think. Suppose $x_0=8$ and $r=2$ - the interval you have at first is $(6, 10)$ and the half interval is $(3,5)$ and these are disjoint from one another.

Comment: Why does the inclusion at the beginning of your final paragraph, $\left( \frac{x_0-r}2,\frac{x_0+r}2\right) \subseteq (x_0-r,x_0+r)$, hold? It wouldn’t if $x_0$ were $10^{10}$ and $r$ were $1$.

Comment: If $x_0-r>0$, $\dfrac{x_0-r}{2}<x_0-r$, which contradicts your claim $(\dfrac{x_0-r}{2},\dfrac{x_0+r}{2}) \subset (x_0-r,x_0+r)$

Comment: You are all right, I confused $\left(\frac{x_0-r}{2},\frac{x_0+r}{2}\right)$ with $\left(x_0-\frac{r}{2},x_0+\frac{r}{2}\right)$, so this doesn't work. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Consider $f(2^n)$ for integer $n$

Comment: More generally, rewrite your equation as $f(x) + f\left(\frac x2\right) = 0$. What then is the relationship of $f\left(\frac x{2^n}\right)$ to $f(x)$? What happens as $n \to \infty$?